# Fix Spotlight results nonsense on Catalina

Tags: spotlight

Here's an example, open Spotlight with <kbd>⌘+Space</kbd>, then type:

1. `d` > `dictionary`;
2. `do` > `docker`;
3. `doc` > `dock`;
4. `dock` > `docker`;
5. `docke` > `docker`;
6. `docker` > `docker`.

Apart from the fact that it is total nonsense IMHO, what's worse is that results change after a few milliseconds, so for example if I type <kbd>⌘+Space doc</kbd> quickly, the initial `docker` result becomes `dock` just before I press enter thus opening Dock.

Is there a way to make Stoplight work "as one would expect" or at least to make it stop changing the result at the last moment?

(In this particular case I could just disable System Preferences results, but that's not a general solution...)

Comment: Spotlight will favour the app you chose last time, so if you select Docker a few times, that will become top of the list. The trouble is that if you press the wrong thing by accident, then that will be top next time, until you've 'retaught' Spotlight.

Comment: This is surely true, but doesn't really explain points 3 and 4... anyway so a complete purge of the prediction cache should do?

Comment: Have you considered using Alfred instead?

Comment: @JBallin thanks for the suggestion, it looks promising, but I find it absurd to resort to third-party software for such basic feature, I hope to find a solution with Spotlight.